Text not scrolling in right direction initially after switching direction
I have a component that should display 4 different sections of text, I want nr 1 to be the intial text and then navigate between them so that if I press nr 2 it scrolls up out of view and the new text scrolls into place from the bottom - and if its the opposite directions it will scroll down (like its a long piece of paper). Right now it works but when I switch direction it initially scrolls the wrong direction before scrolling the correct one after that. I understand that it's something wrong in my component the way it updates, but I can't seem to get it to work.
Main component - WorkProcess.jsx
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { textOptions } from "../../../constants/textOptions";
import WorkProcessList from "./WorkProcessList";
import WorkProcessText from "./WorkProcessText";

function WorkProcess() {
  const [displayedText, setDisplayedText] = useState(textOptions[0].text);
  const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState(textOptions[0].key); // Set activeItem to key

  const handleListItemClick = (text, key) => {
    setDisplayedText(text); // Update the displayed text
    setActiveItem(key); // Set the active item to key
  };

  return (
    <section className="flex flex-col md:flex-row w-[90%] md:w-[80%] lg:w-[60%] justify-center z-10 font-primary">
      <div className="flex items-center justify-center w-full md:w-[20%]"></div>

      <div className="overflow-hidden w-full md:w-[600px] bg-bg h-[300px] rounded-[20px] shadow-inner flex items-center justify-center">
        <WorkProcessText displayedText={displayedText} activeKey={activeItem} />
      </div>

      <div className="text-center md:text-start bg-bg md:bg-none flex items-center justify-center md:justify-start w-full md:w-[20%] py-[3%] md:py-[0%]">
        <WorkProcessList
          activeItem={activeItem}
          handleListItemClick={handleListItemClick}
          textOptions={textOptions}
        />
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

export default WorkProcess;

WorkProcessText.js
import React, { useRef, useLayoutEffect, useState } from "react";
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";

const WorkProcessText = ({ displayedText, activeKey }) => {
  const prevKeyRef = useRef(activeKey); // Keeps track of previous activeKey
  const [direction, setDirection] = useState("up"); // Track direction of scroll

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const prevKey = prevKeyRef.current;

    // Calculate direction based on comparison of current and previous key
    if (activeKey > prevKey) {
      setDirection("up");
    } else if (activeKey < prevKey) {
      setDirection("down");
    }

    // Update prevKeyRef to the current activeKey
    prevKeyRef.current = activeKey;
  }, [activeKey]); // Runs synchronously after activeKey changes

  return (
    <AnimatePresence mode="wait">
      <motion.p
        key={displayedText} // Trigger animation on text change
        className="text-s text-center w-[90%]"
        initial={{ y: direction === "up" ? 300 : -300 }} // Start below for 'up', above for 'down'
        animate={{ y: 0 }} // Animate into the center
        exit={{ y: direction === "up" ? -300 : 300 }} // Exit above for 'up', below for 'down'
        transition={{ duration: 0.3, ease: "easeInOut" }} // Smooth transition
      >
        {displayedText}
      </motion.p>
    </AnimatePresence>
  );
};

export default WorkProcessText;

WorkProcessList.js
import React from "react";

const WorkProcessList = ({ activeItem, handleListItemClick, textOptions }) => {
  return (
    <ul className="text-l leading-none ml-5">
      {textOptions.map(({ key, title, text }) => (
        <li
          key={key}
          onClick={() => handleListItemClick(text, key)} // Pass key instead of item
          className={`transition duration-300 ease-in-out transform hover:text-blue-500 cursor-pointer ${
            activeItem === key ? "text-blue-500" : "" // Compare activeItem with key
          }`}
        >
          {title}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default WorkProcessList;

textOptions.js
export const textOptions = [
  {
    key: 1,
    title: "ONE",
    text: "text one",
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    title: "TWO",

    text: "text two",
  },
  {
    key: 3,
    title: "THREE",
    text: "text three",
  },
  {
    key: 4,
    title: "FOUR",
    text: "text four",
  },
];


In your useLayoutEffect, you're comparing the activeKey state with prevKeyRef.current immediately after setting activeKey. However, because setState is asynchronous in React, the activeKey value used in the direction calculation could be the previous one when it's evaluated.
Replace useLayoutEffect with useEffect to correctly track the previous activeKey value and update the scroll direction after the component renders.


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";

const WorkProcessText = ({ displayedText, activeKey }) => {
  const prevKeyRef = useRef(activeKey); // Keeps track of previous activeKey
  const [direction, setDirection] = useState("up"); // Track direction of scroll

  // This effect will track when the activeKey changes and update the direction
  useEffect(() => {
    const prevKey = prevKeyRef.current;

    // Calculate direction based on comparison of current and previous key
    if (activeKey > prevKey) {
      setDirection("up");
    } else if (activeKey < prevKey) {
      setDirection("down");
    }

    // Update prevKeyRef to the current activeKey after the direction has been set
    prevKeyRef.current = activeKey;
  }, [activeKey]); // This will run whenever activeKey changes

  return (
    <AnimatePresence mode="wait">
      <motion.p
        key={displayedText} // Trigger animation on text change
        className="text-s text-center w-[90%]"
        initial={{ y: direction === "up" ? 300 : -300 }} // Start below for 'up', above for 'down'
        animate={{ y: 0 }} // Animate into the center
        exit={{ y: direction === "up" ? -300 : 300 }} // Exit above for 'up', below for 'down'
        transition={{ duration: 0.3, ease: "easeInOut" }} // Smooth transition
      >
        {displayedText}
      </motion.p>
    </AnimatePresence>
  );
};

export default WorkProcessText;




I understand, it did not work for me and that's what's frustrating me because it feels like that's a logical step.
